# in wordpress, need to know about RSS Feed

Tags: wordpress, rss

I'm new for WordPress. I need to create `RSS Feed` for my site.

What are the steps need?
Need help from staring point.

I don't know anything about RSS Feed.

Answer (score 1):

In short, RSS is a technology that is used by web users to keep track of their favorite websites.

WordPress already has built in support for RSS Feed.

In **Appearance > Widgets** you should find the default RSS widget that provides several basic options, for more control, you can install various plugins.

For introduction about RSS feeds, check [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds) WordPress Codex page.

The above article also has a section that shows you how to Find Your Feed URL.
But if you are using permalinks, your URL would probably be http://www.yourdomain.com/feed/

And here is an [article](http://www.problogger.net/archives/2010/12/03/everything-you-need-to-import-and-display-rss-feeds-with-wordpress/) about how to import and display RSS feeds with WordPress.

Comment: What is 'RSS feed URL here' in Widgets ?

Comment: This link will help you http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds#Finding_Your_Feed_URL

Comment: Chrome is not support the RSS page. What to do?

Comment: You could get the Crome Extension like this one https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-feed-reader/pnjaodmkngahhkoihejjehlcdlnohgmp?hl=en or this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-subscription-extensio/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd?hl=en